# Responsive ULs in a div to fill the space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

Ok, I piggybacked off another users jsfiddle, sorry lost the username :-/

Now, I have created exactly what I want, which is flexible unordered lists which are responsive. Before it was divs, but this is multiple uls.

Here it is, these lists will basically fill the page http://jsfiddle.net/pMF2m/21/

But there is one small thing I want to ask about. I know I can use the provided cutoff points to maintain a nice style at different sizes, but if I have fixed the uls to a set space, then why can I find a point as I shrink the viewport where the last list drops down?

Shouldn't the uls get skinnier and skinnier until we reach the small size defined in the css? Shouldn't it be impossible for this to happen?

Any advice would be appreciated. Again, I know I can and will make several media queries to avoid this, but how can it happen at all?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul class="inner1">
    <li>Hello World I wonder what they will think</li>
    <li>World</li>
    <li>!</li>
    </ul>
        <ul class="inner2">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
    <li>!</li>
    </ul>
        <ul class="inner3">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
    <li>!</li>
    </ul>
</div>

body {
    margin:0;
    border: none;
}
ul,li { padding:2px; list-style:none; }

.outer {
    width: 100%;
}

.outer li {   white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;}

.inner1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left:7%;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
.inner2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;

}
.inner3 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {

    .inner1, .inner2, .inner3 {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        margin-left:0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with inline elements (that includes inline-block elements) when you write them like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

each new line is added as a space between inline elements.

Meaning that it's the same if you have a word divided by space.

So you have `word word word`, those spaces are not taken in consideration and breaks your responsive design.

So what to do?

1) Tha **BAD** way:
You can write them like this:

```
<ul><li>....</li><li>....</li></ul><ul><li>....</li><li>....</li></ul>
```

2) The **GOOD** way

You add `font-size: 0` to the parent of the `ul`-s and add some `font-size` to the `ul`-s that is not zero.

This way the spaces will not take spaces anymore since they have a `font-size: 0`, but we must add some font-size to the `ul`-s too since they will dissapear too and we want to remove only the spaces.

```
.outer {
    font-size: 0;
}
ul { font-size: 14px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pMF2m/22/)

There are other ways to do it with negative magin, but 2) is the most clean way.

Comment: Ok cool! That will help me put the final touches on this page. Thanks!